# is there a good way to calculate sum of product in Rust?

Tags: algorithm, rust, calculation

I'm new to Rust, and I'm looking for a good way to calculate the sum of products in Rust.

I mean if there is a Vector like [3, 4, 5],
I wanna calculate (3 * 4) + (3 * 5) + (4 * 5).

this is my method,

```rust
fn main() {
    let a = [3, 4, 5];
    assert_eq!(
        47,
        [3, 4, 5].iter().enumerate().fold(0, |mut s, (i, v)| {
            for ii in i + 1..a.len() {
                s += *v * a[ii];
            }
            s
        })
    );
}
```

If you know the better one, I'd love to know!

Comment: `a.iter().enumerate().flat_map(|(i, x)| a[i + 1..].iter().map(move |y| x * y)).sum()` (not putting this as an answer because I'm not too sure if this question is appropriate for Stack Overflow)

Comment: The value you are after is `((sum a[i])**2 - sum (a[i]**2))/2`. Linear time complexity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `combinations`, `map` and `sum` or `combinations` and`fold` to implement the product.

```
use itertools::Itertools;
fn main() {
    let a = [3, 4, 5];

    let b: i32 = a.iter().combinations(2).map(|x| x[0] * x[1]).sum();
    assert_eq!(b, 47);

    let c: i32 = a.iter().combinations(2).fold(0, |acc, x| acc + (x[0] * x[1]) );
    assert_eq!(c, 47);

}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2c55770ad35f35d77ad62dc9b3c14aeb)